# No scripts found for hook “after_prepare”. in ionic cordova run android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I ran cmd

> ionic cordova run android

All went well and suddenly I encountered the following error

> [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
>   cordova.cmd build android --verbose exited with exit code 1.

When I did

> ionic cordova run android --verbose

I saw this in cmdline

> Prepared android project successfully 
>   No scripts found for hook “after_prepare”.
>   No scripts found for hook “before_compile”.

Now, I don't know how to solve it. I read a lot of articles but no use. I am working in ionic first time and already faced a lot of issues and now this.

Please any help on this.
I have wasted two days on this issue.

Thanks in advance!